# How to replace multiple chars (not ENG chars like ą,ć,ó,ę to a,c,o,e)

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to replace the values from the column which contains special characters like polish chars ą,ę,ó,ń to eng version a,e,o,n etc. Could you please help me to resolve it?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you define as "English chars"? For example, "naïve", "coöperation", and "coëducation" are perfectly fine English words, "Léon: The Professional" is an English movie title, "Doña Ana" is a county in New Mexico, "Cañones" is a city in New Mexico, "La Cañada Flintridge" is a city in California, "Góra Krzyżanowskiego" is a peak and "Jezioro Piłsudskiego" a lake in Alaska, "Śląsk" is a place in Montana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this quickly using [translate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.translate.html).

#### Translate

```
s = StringIO("""
ID|col1
1|ą,ę,ó,ń
""")

df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter='|')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('translated_col1',F.translate(F.col('col1'),'ąęóń','aeon'))

sparkDF.show()

+---+-------+---------------+
| ID|   col1|translated_col1|
+---+-------+---------------+
|  1|ą,ę,ó,ń|        a,e,o,n|
+---+-------+---------------+
```